# Apache Http Basic Authentication - Forbidden Error 403

Tags: linux, apache, authentication, webserver, http-authentication

I was doing the basic authentication to access the web pages via dispatcher. I have gone through some blog and was able to achieve it, but only for one directory. Below is the virtual host that i configured.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@aemcorner.com
    ServerName aemcorner.com
    ServerAlias www.aemcorner.com
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
        DocumentRoot /opt/communique/dispatcher/cache
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
       <Directory /content/practice/en/hello/secure-pages>
   # <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
          AuthType Basic
          AuthName "Secure Content"
          AuthBasicProvider file
          AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
          Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here i want to work with the commented lines, this snippet work fine but when i
replace it with **/content/practice/en/Secure-Pages** and use the commented DocumentRoot it give me an error as below :

```
**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /content/practice/en/hello/secure-pages/sp1.html on this server.**
```

I want to access the page `/opt/communique/dispatcher/cache/content/practice/en/Secure-Pages/SP1.html`

Also i am getting the below error :

```
[Mon Sep 07 20:57:39.500158 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 9483:tid 140017092585216] [client 127.0.0.1:49543] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/communique/dispatcher/cache/favicon.ico, referer: http://aemcorner.com/content/practice/en/hello/secure-pages/sp1.html
```

Comment: The path of the file you're attempting to access is not within the path of the directory to which you're trying to allow access. Also make sure you're consistent with case sensitivity. Try changing to `<Directory /content/practice/en/hello/secure-pages>`

Comment: yes i did this, when i hit http://aemcorner.com/content/practice/en/hello/secure-pages/sp1.html url, it gives me same message You don't have permission to access /content/practice/en/hello/secure-pages/sp1.html on this server. updating question also

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem via below configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@aemcorner.com
    ServerName aemcorner.com
    ServerAlias www.aemcorner.com
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
        DocumentRoot /opt/communique/dispatcher/cache
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
       <Location /content/practice/en/hello/secure-pages>
   # <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
          AuthType Basic
          AuthName "Secure Content"
          AuthBasicProvider file
          AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
          Require valid-user
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have use `Location` instead of Directory and  `Require valid-user`